# How to make a screenshot of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, screenshot, android-checkbox

I have a nice question :). I would create a checkbox that if activated the phone makes a screenshot of a specific `Activity` of the application in a specific hour. I mean: click on the checkbox, and at 12.00 AM automatically i'll have a screenshot of the main `Activity` for example. Is it possible? Is root required?

Comment: What have tried so far.?? Where are you stuck ??

Answer (score 0):

There's no root needed.
check this:

http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/

next check the `AlarmManager`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html